# SQL Server Session Serialization in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, session, serialization

I am new to ASP.Net MVC . Any help is greatly appreciated in resolving my problem.

I am using a LINQToSQL db in my MVC application. For one of the auto generated partial class (Example MyClass assume for table MyClass) , I created another Partial class as MyClass and added DataAnnotations Like following...

```
namespcae NP
{
 [MetadaType(typeof(myData))]
[Serializable()]
public partial class MyClass
{

 }

 public myData 
{
   [Required]
   public string ID { get ; set ;}

   // Other properties are listed here

}
}
```

In my controller class example MyHomeController

I have a code as follows:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();

list = dbContext.StoredProcedure(null).ToList<MyClass>()
session["data"] = list.
```

above code works fine if I use inProc session state. But if I use SQLServer mode then I get error as

> "Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode. "

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here..?. I can see the data is getting populated in ASPState database tables. By application throws error as follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the issue.

Solution:
Add the below statement before querying the database. In my case I was calling LinqToSQl context( dbContext).

dbContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

Sample Code:

List empList = new List();
dbContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
empList =  dbContext.SomeStoredProcedure().ToList()
Session["employee"] = empList.

Answer (score 0):

Just mark as Serializable all classes whose instances you want to store in Session.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As you can see from my code..I have put the serialize attribute on the partial class MyClass. Still the application throws error. SO far only one instance of class is being used by the application.

Comment: I suspect there is member in MyClass that should also be marked as Serializable.

Comment: Whats the best way to find the member that also needs to be set as serialize ?